# Is there a way to see an application's configuration in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

Symfony2 Applications have their configuration stored in different files throughout the application, in different packages. You can even overwrite values in lower packages.

This can often get confusing as you need to know what a configuration setting is, but do not know where to look or cannot quickly find it.

It gets even worse when you find the setting, only to realise later that that setting isn't actually used because it's overwritten somewhere else.

Is there a command, plugin, or anything that lets you see *all* the configuration in a single location, the way it is *actually used by Symfony2*?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current configuration for a bundle using the `debug:config` (with the alias `config:debug`) command. From what I can see the `debug:config` command appeared in 2.5 although the `config:debug` may have been around a long time before.

For example, to get the config for the FOSUserBundle your would use

```
app/console debug:config fos_user
```

Comment: The question is about the runtime configuration, and this answer is about static configuration exposed by bundles.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess using `app/console debug:container` for services and `app/console debug:container --parameters` for parameters may be able to help.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing you can do to get a complete picture of the whole application at runtime, but you can catch parts of it.

First thing to do is explore the profiler:

[image: sfDebug]

You will have access to the Request, the logs, the routing...

What you can do next, if this is not enougth, is dumping the container.

```
dump($this->container);
```

From a Controller i.e. This will contains all the parameters, all the service definitions and so on.